# Imposing restriction over some regressors in a linear model?

Tags: multiple-regression, contrasts, constrained-regression

I have the following problem:
Starting with a multivariate linear model $Y=\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2+\beta_3x_3+\beta_4x_4+\alpha_1x_5+\alpha_2x_6+\alpha_3x_7+\alpha_4x_8+\epsilon$ and $$X=\begin{pmatrix} 
1&-1&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
1&0&-1&0&1&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&-1&1&0&0&0\\
-1&1&0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&1&-1&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&-1&0&1&0&0\\
-1&0&1&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&-1&1&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&-1&0&0&1&0\\
-1&0&0&1&0&0&0&1\\
0&-1&0&1&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&-1&1&0&0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix} $$

How would you impose the restriction $\sum_{i=1}^4 \beta_i=0$ to run the regression on R?

Giving you the context of this question, there is an article published in 1995 by Clarke and Norman with title "Home ground advantage of individual clubs in English soccer" in which this model is used. After a lot of time spent in google, books and this forum I found that maybe with contrast=contr.sum (changing the contrast level to sum cero) could do the trick BUT it changes the $\alpha$'s too.

What would you do?

Thank you for your help :)